# Android: How to resize image to fill parent?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-xml, scaletype

I am working on application which shows images, and I need to create a view which shows big images in a 1:1 aspect ratio.

First, I have thumbnails which are at a `72x72` resolution. I have put them in an `ImageView` but even if I add the parameters `android:width="fill_parent"` and `android:height="wrap_content"`, the image would not be not the size of the `ImageView` but is only centered in the mid.

I tried adding the parameter `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` which resized the image well horizontally but the height remained the same.

How could I set up my `ImageView` so that it would be on all devices as width as the parent view and it should also be as height.

I can do this programatically, but I need to be able to do it in XML.

### My XML File:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    // The ImageView I am talking about above
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/invitation_imageview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/face_woman_smile" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/invitation_avatar_view_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/face_woman_smile"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set the images as `android:background` and they will be stretched to match the parent size.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you need to add this to your ImageView

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: this will not resize it properly

Answer (score 3):

**To make image stretch to parent's width while keeping aspect ratio**

Set

1- `android:layout_width` to `match_parent`

2- `layout_height` to `wrap_content`

3- `adjustViewBounds` to `true`

Like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/unknown"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

**Note:** This might not render correctly in Preview but would work on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `android:width="match_parent"` and `android:height="wrap_content"`, as you mentioned, but I use `android:scaleType` for my `ImageView` layouts.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/clear-up-ambiguity-about-android-image-view-scale-types-with-this-guide/).